# Save a canvas with CSS3 filters applied as an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have applied some CSS3 filters to an image on a canvas like this:

```
-webkit-filter brightness(0%) grayscale(100%) contrast(1000%)
```

But when I save the image to my computer, the original image is being saved, not the one with applied filters. Is there a way to save the modified version of it?

Comment: You need to apply filter to canvas pixels (i.e. modifying each pixel color values). That's [how we do it in Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/), for example.

Comment: You will need to use WebGL to apply the filters instead.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the filter in the canvas using a shader, rather than using a CSS style.

<s>Alternately, make a hidden canvas, draw your content to that, apply the CSS3 filter to it, and then use that canvas to output to the visible one.</s>

Comment: Even if I apply the filter to the canvas, for example, make it grayscale, and it looks grayscale on the screen, it doesn't save it as a grayscale image to the file. It saves the original one.

Comment: The CSS filter is applied to the canvas element, not to the data it contains. As such, you can't output a filtered canvas to a "main" canvas. You'll just have 2 identical copies

Comment: So, are there any solutions? =)

Comment: I'm afraid not, the canvas has no "access" to the styles applied to it.

Comment: Put the filtered canvas into SVG `foreignObject`, then [insert the serialised SVG](http://svgopen.org/2010/papers/62-From_SVG_to_Canvas_and_Back/#svg_to_canvas) as a Base64-encoded image into the visible canvas. (Just kidding)

Answer (score 0):

The filters style the canvas element, not the canvas content.
As far as I'm aware, you can't convert a section (Canvas+ styling) of a page to a image.

To clarify: CSS styles are applied to the DOM element, not to the data in the element.
In this case, that means the actual data that is the image on the canvas, is not modified when you apply a CSS shade or something, to the canvas.

Yes, you can save a canvas's data, but no, CSS styles will not be reflected on it.

Comment: This library http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/  lets you save a HTML5 canvas element as an imagefile. May be it will work for your case.

Comment: It will not. The CSS style is not applied to the data in the canvas. That library saves the canvasdata with `toDataURL()`.